# Weather Underground API with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am supposed to create an app with the Weather Underground API using Ajax and JSON but there really wasn't much direction as to how to go about it. If I could see a completed version of the code so I have some idea of how I should even begin. That's how I learn. I know a little about JSON but I'm not sure what my next step is here.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Your Name
Date
Month
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weather API App</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="http://icons.wxug.com/logos/PNG/wundergroundLogo_4c_horz.png" alt="logo"/>
            <h1>Your Awesome Forecast Page</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forecasts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="conditions">
            <h2>Current Conditions</h2>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <div class="window1">

            </div>
            <p>
                <!--  1. Display the icon for the current conditions (observation)
                2. Display weather
                3. Display temperature in Ferinheiths
                4. Display feels like temperature
                5. Display relative humidity
                6. Display wind direction
                7. Display wind miles per hour
            -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hourly">
            <h2>Your Hourly 1-day forecast</h2>
            <p>
            <!--  1. Display the Hourly 1-day forecast
            2. Display the condition for each hour
            3. Display the temperature for each hour
            -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="7_day">
            <h2>Your 7-day forecast</h2>
            <p>
            <!--    1. Display the 7-day forecast
            2. Display the icon
            3. Display weather
            4. Display highs
            5. Display lows
        -->
            </p>
        </div>

    </div><!--Closes Container-->
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:darkblue;
}

#container{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Header
------------------------------*/
header {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

main.js

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ef5a156e62f050d2/conditions/q/OH/Columbus.json",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(url) {
        var location = url['location']['city'];
        var temp_f = url['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        $(".conditions").html("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f+"ºF");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a programmer forum to get specific answers on development questions.  I'd suggest searching on Google for some tutorials, getting a few books to read, or perhaps some online courses.  You probably won't find anyone willing to write an entire program for you.

Comment: Oh yeah, the way I worded that made it sound like I wanted a complete version of it. I only want to know what I'm doing wrong. I can figure out how to write the part in my html. I just know I'm doing something wrong in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start to get you going.  Your AJAX function returns JSON data (open your console and take a look).  The correct way to retrieve any particular key/value from the JSON data is as shown below for temp_f.  Then, as you have already done, build a string from the various elements you have extracted from the JSON, and write it to your selected HTML element:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ef5a156e62f050d2/conditions/q/OH/Columbus.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(url) {
    console.log(url);
    var location = 'Columbus';
    var temp_f = url.current_observation.temp_f;
    $(".conditions").html("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f + "ºF");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conditions"></div>
```

Comment: That actually helps! Thank you! Also I feel really dumb for not linking jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @sideroxylon's answer , this is just as a sidenote.

If you are exclusively expecting to retrieve just JSON data, it'd be worth exploring to use the `$.getJSON` function as well, if you do not want to worry about the datatype that you're using in `$.ajax` , see my `jquery` snippet below.

---

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.wunderground.com/api/ef5a156e62f050d2/conditions/q/OH/Columbus.json", function(response) {
    var location = response['current_observation']['display_location']['city'];
    var temp_f = response['current_observation']['temp_f'];
    $(".conditions").html("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f + "ºF");
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conditions">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!