# Not able to parse JSON response from Weather Underground API

Tags: ajax, geolocation, weather-api

I am trying to create a simple weather page. I want to retrieve coordinates of the user location and subsequently the weather information of location from Weather Underground API. I am able to get to see the JSON response for my coordinates. However, i am having problem parsing JSON using AJAX function and show it on HTML. Below is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<body>
<div id="forecast">
<h1>Weather at <span id="location"> </span></h1>
<div id="imgdiv">
<img id="img" src=""/>
</div>
<p>It is currently <span id="temp"> </span>°C with <span id="desc"> </span></p>
<p>Wind: <span id="wind"></span></p>

</body>
</div>
```

JQuery;

```
    var Geo={};
     var temp_f
        //var key = ‘4d6eb96f1aa092b2’;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
        }
        else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported');
        }

        function error() {
        alert("That's weird! We couldn't find you!");
        }

   function success(position) {
              Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
              Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
              Geo.url   = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/4d6eb96f1aa092b2/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/" + Geo.lat + "," + Geo.lng + ".json"; 

     $.ajax({
    url : Geo.url,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(url) {
         location = url['location']['city'];
         temp_f = url['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        $("#temp").html(temp_f);
    }
   });

}
```

I get location and temp_f value as `undefined`. I referred very similar post [Weather Underground API with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518066/weather-underground-api-with-ajax) yet not able to figure out what is the problem ?  I am new this so please excuse  if am missing something basic.

Comment: do alert(JSON.stringify(url)) or console.log(JSON.stringify(url)) and see what the response you get, Also please post it here

Comment: it gives 'undefined'

Comment: what is the value of Geo.lat and Geo.lng ?

Comment: for example ; Geo.lat: 51.9623682, Geo.lng: 7.595598700000001, the complete URL : http://api.wunderground.com/api/4d6eb96f1aa092b2/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/51.9623682,7.595598700000001.json

Comment: did you get any error in console ?

Comment: no error.. just returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me check: https://jsfiddle.net/jigarb1992/q1w8usq9/

The problem I found in your code is may be here `location = url['location']['city'];`, the `location` in `javascript` will redirect you to given location.

Try the code I have do changes in **jsfiddle**

Comment: Yes, seems to work now. May be the problem was with declaring variables which is unecessary though. Thanks for your help